# How to fix Spring Security Oauth 2.0 tonr & sparklr application error?

Tags: security, spring, oauth-2.0

I am trying sample application "sparklr" and "tonr" packaged with Spring Security OAuth 2.0. Unfortunately, I failed to make these applications work correctly as described in the Spring Security website.

To be specific, I tried two versions of Spring Security OAuth 2.0, one is M5 , the other is the master.

For M5, a exception is thrown out when visiting "sparklr" app with the error message "No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined". Accessing sparklr photo through "tonr" application received a blank page as well.

For the master version, the blank page is always returned for any request to both applications.

Is there anyone who has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the exception problem on M5 by commenting out the "oauth2EndpointUrlFilter" configuration in Sparklr app's web.xml as below.

```
- <!-- filter>
    <filter-name>oauth2EndpointUrlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>oauth2EndpointUrlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping
-->
```